# How do I determine whether an environment entry is a bash function or not?

Tags: bash, function, environment-variables

In Perl, `%ENV` gives access to the environment:

```
e='() {  echo This is not a func
}'
d() {  echo This is a func
}
export e
export -f d
perl -e 'print $ENV{"d"},"\n",$ENV{"e"},"\n"'
```

But I have not found a way to tell whether **d** or **e** is a bash function. How can I do that from Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell built-in [`type -t`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type) will return the string `function`.

```
perl -e 'print qx(bash -c "type -t e")'
```

Comment: Your command above gives 'function'. But `e` is not a function.

Comment: For the shell, it is. Once a function body is serialised into the environment, it becomes a mere string, not distinguishable from mundane strings. In fact, `perl -e 'print qx(bash -c "e")'` will run and echo `This is not a func`. You found an edge-case where the heuristic fails your expectation, deal with it.

Comment: Analysing this further it seems the edge case is if the variable starts with '() {' then it is treated as a function - no matter if it is a function or not (e.g. the ending } can be missing). So that means that I can simply look for '() {' as the first 4 chars; no need to spawn a shell.

Comment: Which makes for a good bash trivia: What does this print: i='() {' bash -c 'echo $i'